# make the text inside a text area become a variable once a button is clicked

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to return all the text inside a textarea or an input as a variable on button click using jQuery or javascript.

A .select() function does not seem to do this, and spits out a lot of css properties when logged

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: It looks like you need that : http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is it:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#le_button").click(function() {
                var input_value = $("#le_input").val(); //get the value
                alert(input_value); //do what ever you want, it is on a variable
            });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<textarea id="le_input">lorem ipsum</textarea>
<button id="le_button">click me!</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this? `$('#id_of_or_input').val()`